# WPF. Как вставить картинку в Image, преобразованную из потока байтов

Tags: c#, wpf, serialize

```
maintStream = client.GetStream();
Image image = (Image) binFormatter.Deserialize(maintStream);
```

Вот я получил с клиента данные, которые поступают раз в секунду. Как мне их вставить в image WPF?

Comment: Через Source???

Comment: Так а разве Source может принимать данные не в виде ссылки? А если я буду сохранят картинку каждую секунду, и выводить ее, то мне кажется это не самый лучший вариант

Comment: ImageComponent.Source = image.Source;

Comment: Source, это вообще то не string и не Uri, а [ImageSource](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.windows.media.imagesource(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: А какого типа ваш `Image`? Это `System.Drawing.Image` или `System.Windows.Controls.Image`? И почему вы перегоняете по сети внутренний .NET-овский класс, а не саму картинку?